# Razor syntax highlighting in VS2015 RTM

Tags: razor, visual-studio-2015

I've got an issue with VS2015 and razor syntax highlighting.

I'm not using `System.Web.Mvc` or `System.Web.WebPages`, just `System.Web.Razor` directly to render some HTML.

In web web.config I have the below, which worked fine in VS2013:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="MyProj, RazorView" >
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

none of the `namespaces` are being imported by VS, so everything is red and squiggly.

I've tried the `/ResetUserData` trick from the RC, but to no avail. What can I try next?

Comment: While you do not need those assemblies at runtime to render Razor as text, the designer does need them at development time (at least if it is the same as earlier VS versions).

Comment: Same issue but I have referenced all valid MVC / Razor assemblies. Syntax highlighting in VS2015 Professional does not work. All of the tricks posted on StackOverflow have not fixed the issue.